# Python code percentage number compare problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i compared tow percentage number it gives me wrong answer

```
a="{0:%}".format(85/100)
b="{0:%}".format(9/100)

if b>a :
    print("done")
```

it should be pass if condition while its give me done in answer

Comment: They are strings. The comparison is lexicographical

Comment: You compare lexicographical.  `'9'` is bigger then `'111111111111111111'`

Comment: You are converting `a` and `b` which are strings, you want to compare floats, `(85/100)>(9/100)`

Answer (score 1):

> when i compare two percentage numbers it gives me wrong answer

No, the interpreter gives the correct answer.

The variables get these string values:

```
a = '85.000000%'
b = '9.000000%'
```

You are complaining about this string comparison result:

```
>>> '9' > '85'
True
```

Or more simply, since they differ in the 1st character, about this result:

```
>>> '9' > '8'
True
```

If you would prefer a numeric comparison,
then strip the percent and recover the numbers:

```
>>> float(b[:-1]) > float(a[:-1])
False
```